# JavaFX SceneBuilder controller clases and onActionEvents are doesn't applied by default?

Tags: javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

**About my scene builder :**

Product Version
JavaFX Scene Builder 8.4.1

Build Information
Version 8.4.1
Date: 2017-10-17
Java Version: 1.8.0_144-b01, Oracle Corporation

Logging
The default configuration stores logging output in a file named
 scenebuilder-8.4.1.log (possibly followed by a trailing '.' and a digit).
The default file path is /tmp/scenebuilder-8.4.1.log

JavaFX
Toolkit = QuantumToolkit
Pipeline = ES2Pipeline
Hardware acceleration ENABLED

Java
1.8.0_144-b01, Oracle Corporation

Operating System
Linux, amd64, 4.9.0-deepin10-amd64

Copyright (c) 2015-2017, Gluon.

and i use **Netbeans 8.02 IDE** when i open fxml file from netbeans ide, but that scene bulder app hasn't minimize,close and maximize buttons. i trying to fix that problem **press alt+space** . but it also doesn't fixed. so that, i couldn't get **controller sceleton** also.

and, **controller class and #onActionEvent** also doesn't applied by default?

[image: #onActionEvent doesn't applied like this]

what is this wrong? Scenebuilder IDE or another?

*please help me! Thank you!*

Comment: When you open Scene Builder as standalone app or from NetBeans, you never see the window buttons (close, minimize, maximize)? I don't see the app title "Scene Builder" in your screenshot. It should be on top of the menu, and containing the buttons. Can you find it? As for the skeleton, you have to copy from Scene Builder and paste it to the JavaFX controller in your IDE.

Comment: @JoséPereda any time, app title and window buttons doesn't display. when i clicked, **Alt+Space** , there also **unmaximized** option doesn't it. not only that, but also when i use skeleton window, that also always on under the scene builder app. so that, couldn't copy skeleton.

Comment: So it seems all the dialogs that pop up from the application are underneath it? Can you drag/resize the app with the mouse and find and close them?

Comment: @JoséPereda  yes sir! all the dialogs are underneath. and can't drag/resize the app with mouse and close dialogs.

Comment: is this a Scene Builder app problem or other?

Comment: I would say that it is a problem of a JavaFX maximized app running on your Linux distribution. Maybe you can edit and play with the settings here: `<user.home>/.scenebuilder`?